# SharePoint Online Connectivity With External Database

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

i want to read/write data to external database from SharePoint online. i want to discuss pro and cons of BCS (Business connectivity services) and WCF approach. i have office 365 E3 plan and has oracle database( installed on premise). any help appreciated.